# What is the purpose of aria-label="Left Align" in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been reading bootstrap on their official page. In [an example](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-examples) they used the attribute `aria-label` as:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute) says `area-label` is used by assistive technologies such as screen readers. But what does the values `left align` suggest to assistive technologies?

Comment: That the user should be told, in english, that clicking the button will align something to the left.

Answer (score 0):

It is a label for the assistive technologies.  In case someone need a screen reader, that attribute specify the text to read.

I found [this](https://danielnixon.org/bootstraps-bad-glyphicon-example/) article that talks about the exatly same page ;)